Is there a nonlinear resistor with a zero or infinite differential resistance?
By negative resistor, I mean a passive 1-port with a one-to-one, continuous current-voltage characteristic \$(i, v)\$ that lies in the \$(+, +)\$ and \$(-, -)\$ sectors. working definition of differential resistance
So I'm envisioning an i-v characteristic like \$i \propto v^3\$ or \$v \propto i^3\$. Are these physically realizable?
The only physical nonlinear resistor I know of is a diode, which is locally linear around the origin. (On the contrary, I am asking for a current-voltage characteristic that is singular at the origin.)

I'm confused by a couple of things. You start by defining "negative resistor" even though you haven't used the term "negative resistor" anywhere else in your question; was that a typo for "nonlinear resistor"? Also, you're asking for the i-v characteristic to be "singular" at the origin, and to perhaps be similar to $i \propto v^3$, but to me, that curve isn't singular at the origin. Can you confirm that when you say "singular," you mean a zero or infinite slope?

There are negative resistor equivalents, but it's not going to be in the form of a single component. It'll be in the form of some kind of active component stage. You could probably realize this with opamps, and log amplifier stages somehow. And dioes are not resistive, a resistor has a linear relationship between V and I

Differential resistance is given by
$$r_d = \frac{\partial V}{\partial I}$$
A tunnel diode has two points in it's VI characteristic curve where the differential resistance is \$\infty\$.

In this image, from Wikipedia the points \$(V_1,i_1)\$ and \$(V_2,i_2)\$ have such infinite differential resistance. In between those points, the tunnel diode has negative differential resistance.

Actually the peaks are infinity, as the (incremental) resistance goes from positive, through infinity, wrapping around from negative infinity. (A cool reminder that the real numbers form a continuous ring, with +/- ∞'s connected.  At least, under certain definitions -- here, the equivalence is the map x --> 1/x.) A "Z type" negative resistance device has the inverse case at the corresponding peaks.

@TimWilliams You are right. Good catch. I was thinking "slope", but slope in that diagram is the inverse of differential resistance.

Do you know of any nonlinear resistor that's singular around $i = 0, v =0$?

@SimonKuang I think you could make this into such a device by adding a voltage source in series and a current source in parallel. Would that work for your purposes?

The classics remain relevant; though neon bulbs are largely obsolete for indication and electronic purposes, the fundamentals they demonstrate will never go away.  Consider the curve from Dougherty, et al, General Electric Glow Lamp Manual, 2nd Ed., General Electric Company (1966):

A neon tube can be used as a voltage regulator, when biased to point F or H, corresponding to the physical phenomenon of normal glow to abnormal glow.  (They note, most devices are operated between F and somewhat beyond but still near G.)  Ranges E-F or H-J can be used for negative-resistance oscillators, and points F and H have zero dynamic (or incremental, or differential) resistance, with the resistance being above or below zero for locations around those points.
With the plot transposed, making the voltage axis horizontal, we describe this as "Z type" negative resistance: the current stays low for most voltages (starting from zero), then rises gently; ignition occurs then voltage drops sharply as current increases (E-F); then voltage rises again as resistance (or other effects) dominate.  (In this case, there can be a second 'Z'-ing of the curve, as arc discharge takes over in the J region.  I guess that makes it more of a ξ curve?)
(This complements Math's answer, which gives an "N-type" negative resistance example.  There are contemporary examples of that as well, like secondary emission in tetrodes ("tetrode kink"), or various point-contact junctions analogous to tunnel diodes but predating the proper Si or Ge components, Iron Pyrites Negative Resistance Oscillator | Sparkbangbuzz for example, and other Z-type curves; though I don't think they were ever reliable or consistent enough for commercial production until the development of Ge and Si.  As scientific curiosities, they have been long known, though.)

I think this answer extends to other similar phenomena like SCR or DIACs, though their hysteretic switching between the high-resistance and the "triggered" state might have to suppressed with appropriate series resistancd.

The curve you suggest (\$i\$ \$\alpha\$ \$  v^3 \$) looks like this (graph created by mathway.com):

That's similar in general form to the behavior of a bipolar TVS:

The differential resistance does not go to zero, but it's a heck of a lot less above the breakdown voltage than it is near zero.
There's a two pin bidirectional device called a diac that actually has negative differential resistance at the breakdown point, though it arguably is not 'passive'.


The only physical nonlinear resistor I know of is a diode,

An ordinary silicon diode (following the Shockley equation) has approximately infinite differential resistance when strongly reverse biased. This is the property we use when we use a diode an RF switch.
Of course to take advantage of this you must avoid biasing the diode so strongly in reverse that it enters the reverse breakdown operating regime.

which is locally linear around the origin.

In small signal analysis we treat any nonlinear resistor (with a continuous I-V curve) as being locally linear about whatever operating point we are using.


we treat any nonlinear resistor (with a continuous I-V curve) as being locally linear

But my question is asking about cases where the linearization has zero or infinite slope.

In just saying that being locally linear isn't some rare property. It happens at any operating point of any device with a continuous IV curve (and all the points that don't have discontinuities in devices without continuous IV curves).

Superconductors
For small currents in a type I superconductors, there is no resistance. Current flows but there is no voltage difference across the superconductor.  If the current increases, then at some critical current, the superconductor abruptly goes normal (ceases to superconduct, usually it becomes a normal metal).
In theory, one could drive a superconductor into the normal state, then drop the current and recover the superconducting state.  So one would have a region where both the resistance and differential resistance are zero, then a point with infinite differential resistance, then a region with normal resistive behaviour.
In practice, the critical current falls as temperature increases. So if any part of the superconductor reaches the critical current, it starts to heat the surrounding material, and that surrounding material quickly goes normal too.  This is known as a "quench".
Superconductors only superconduct when very cold. At least -135°C, and for type I, more like -265°C. So you don't see them in any common electronics. But they are used to build circuits in physics research, MRI machines, and quantum computing.
One can also use superconductors to make more complex devices with even stranger IV curves, such as Superconducting Tunnel Junctions and SQUIDs.

Maybe this matches your description:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

\$r = \frac{dV}{dI} = \infty \$ for \$I=0\$, and the curve stays in quadrants 1 (+,+) and 3 (−,−).

This is a repetition of ThePhoton's answer, to which the OP already reiterate that it does not answer the question, so -1

@tobalt This is not the same as ThePhoton's answer.  Simon is pointing out that ordinary diodes meet the requirement with forward bias.

@MattTimmermans And the OP pointed out that regular diodes don't meet the requirement at all.

@tobalt I get the downvote, because I agree with you to a great extent, and I am aware that OP ruled out the diode. The question for me really is why did he rule it out? Is it because picoamps per volt is too conductive? I would argue that you'd have a hard time finding a resistor or PCB to outperform that. If that's indeed the problem, then what about two back-to-back JFET junctions? I wonder if that's an acceptable idea for OP.

Simon I think, if you read the answers about the gas discharge tube and tunnel diode, it becomes rather clear that any device with a fundamentally finite differential resistance is not the scope of the question. In a normal world, this question would be well suited to physics.SE. But in reality EE.SE gives better answers to this end, because physics.SE is useless for remotely practical questions.
